# NodeJS: Connect my Google App Engine app to my Cloud SQL databases

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Help needed. On my local Mac, I use the following code to connect my app to my MySQL database, and it works perfectly on my local computer.

const pool = mysql.createConnection({ //
password: 'x142a0ejeqee', // my password
user: 'myusername',
database: 'mydatabase_name',
host: 'localhost',
port: '3306'
});

Now, I want to deploy my app to the World. I uploaded all of the files in App Engine (Google Cloud), but I cannot connect my app to my databases (MySQL on Cloud SQL). Help. Anyone has a code that helps?

Comment: so you have mysql installed on your computer that is why localhost works, but whgen you run your app on a different computer localhost will pint to that computer and unless you installed mysql there, you wil get no repsonse. better solution ist to use A REST API to  a myslq server in the intenet, but as the REST api suggests not dorectly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to connect locally to a MySQL database and the steps to connect remotely to a Cloud SQL instance differ slightly in nature.

I would recommend following this [Connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard) guide for the specific implementation walk through.